# Incorrect title of “new” tag info tab

Tags: bug, answers, tag-wiki

Every tag info page has a tab with new answers, for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/new

The title of that page is "Answers By New Users" which is weirdly capitalized and more importantly, incorrect. The page shows all new answers, not only those by new users.

[image: title]

The incorrect string propagated to [pt.SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/new) as well, although capitalization was fixed:

> Respostas por novos usuários de 'java'